# Not sure how to do this countifs function correctly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have this table below

[image: Order Info]

What I want is able to pivot for number of items(column) ordered by days (row). I'm not sure how to do it smartly. So I thought of a way which is to create a table below

[image]

However, when I tried writing a countifs, it gives me error. What I tried for each row was:
=countifs(range of item 1 to item 3,  that item, range of the whole Order Date column, that date). But it throws me an #VALUE error.  More details below

[image]

So yeah, I'm stuck. Can someone please help? I'm using Excel 2019 by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `COUNTIFS` function each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as first range.

But I can suggest the `SUMPRODUCT` function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(([@Item]=Table1[[Item 1]:[Item 3]])*([@Date]=Table1[Order Date]))
```

[image]

Comment: nice. I'll give this a try then

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much for saving my life!